# why does npe detect miktex-texworks.exe as a virus?

Tags: windows, miktex, norton

I was worried that my Windows 10 machine was compromised and ran Norton Power Eraser.

It suggested that miktex-texworks.exe was a virus (see attachment).

Are there issues with TexWork and should I take up the suggestion to remove?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not unusual. I'm experiencing the same with Norton Symantec Endpoint Protection. This is an overreaction of the product as it attacks almost everything. Thus, the Norton stuff behaves itself like a virus. So, there are no issues with TexWorks and I wouldn't recommend to remove it. If you have possibility to edit the Whitelist of the power eraser then do it and it will hopefully leave in peace.